# List group with linked item with background color in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Bootstrap version: Bootstrap v3.0.0
Using the bootstrap example for bootstrap list group with linked items:

```
   <div class="list-group">
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">
    Cras justo odio
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</a>
</div>
```

I need to change the background color as a `Contextual classes`

```
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-success">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
  <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-info">Cras sit amet nibh libero</li>
  <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-warning">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
  <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-danger">Vestibulum at eros</li>
</ul>
```

The trick part is I can't merge both examples, and the following combinations doesn't work:

```
<a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-danger">

<a href="#" class="list-group-item bg-danger">

<a href="#" class="list-group-item danger">
```

So the question....

**Is possible to change this with bootstrap class, or maybe overriding some css?**

Thanks and kind regards.

**UPDATE:**
Suggested answer is working on fiddle but not in my code.
Bootstrap version: Bootstrap v3.0.0
The group is in a panel content.

[image]

Complete code:

```
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="list-group">
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-danger">Dapibus ac facilisis in</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-warning">Morbi leo risus</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-success">Porta ac consectetur ac</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-info">Vestibulum at eros</a>
</div>
   </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: That is a statement with a question mark at the end. Try setting whatever property you choose to your preferred value, followed by `!important`

Comment: thanks, sorry for my english

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*EDIT: The following only works with Bootstrap v3.1.0+, if you absolutely need to use an older version you need to use custom classes and style them with CSS.*

your first combination works perfectly.

Please make sure that you follow the exact structure for the component, in your case *List-Group with Linked Items* which has a structure like :

```
<div class="list-group">
    <a class="list-group-item"></a>
    <a class="list-group-item"></a>
    ...
</div>
```

and then add the styling classes to the anchors `<a>`.

In the end it should look like this :

```
<div class="list-group">
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-danger">Dapibus ac facilisis in</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-warning">Morbi leo risus</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-success">Porta ac consectetur ac</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-info">Vestibulum at eros</a>
</div>
```

Please have a look at the fiddle here that shows this working : https://jsfiddle.net/bafforosso/whLhohew/

Comment: I still can't see the the colors. Please review my update. Thanks!

Comment: Is the fiddle working on your browser?
If yes have you tried mirroring it on your page?

Comment: Yes. I'll try updating the bootstrap version

Comment: @LeandroTupone it doesn't work with Bootstrap v3.0.0, see example fiddle with 3.0.0 here: https://jsfiddle.net/bafforosso/dzu5fymr/
If you want to use Bootstrap classes to style this you'll need to use a newer version of Bootstrap. Otherwise you'll need to create some custom classes and style them in CSS